# HTTP Error 400: Bad Request on getting the facebook's post likes in python

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I wrote the code of getting the Facebook's post data about 8 months ago, was working fine but now I run the code and I am getting 
the exception of

> HTTP Error 400: Bad Request.

It is on getting the `likes` of a post. The link is

`https://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/143462899029472_1786215864754159 fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)&access_token=*************UmG4GyioZATAGkzXSP5k7IxqsRCpIBxhD5EvNxHAwuZAOIp3ksLWTZA0yMgvEuST1oHBNfgSZCCcYG0vZAqNitdSNoIObWagZC8oZATOfYVmBldQWjayZA0fv7zrCZAvlsGymC2w5vKzETUJiogzSIQoKAzy2UTJJ4UUmmGPKEZD`

On manually accessing the link in browser it is giving;

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (likes) on node type (URL)",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 100,
      "fbtrace_id": "Bj6UP6k1Mu2"
   }
}
```

Any help? Why it is so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved. My bad. I use the link `https://graph.facebook.com/https://www.facebook.com/143462899029472_1786215864754159 fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)&access_token=.....`
Notice in the link `https://graph.facebook.com/` and then unfortunately `https://www.facebook.com/` in one link. 
The problem is resolved by using only `https://graph.facebook.com/143462899029472_1786215864754159 fields=likes.limit(0).summary(true)&access_token=.....`

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is so?

Because they make changes to the API. You did not specify an API version in your API call, so it will fall back to the lowest one your app can use. And when that gets shut of, it moves to the next version, and so on.

But your approach was rather convoluted to begin with. This is a post *on* Facebook, so why treat it as an *external* URL?

All you need to do is make a request using the post id - then you can request the likes for that post directly.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=143462899029472_1786215864754159%3Ffields%3Dlikes.limit(0).summary(1)&version=v2.8

Comment: See my answer below.